# How to tell the real source of an error in a callback?

Tags: javascript, error-handling

This is probably very basic but I'm new to JavaScript and apparently don't know the right search terms for it.

I'm trying to use a function as a callback in possibly multiple places. However, I can't figure out how to make the callback function tell me the real source of the error.

```js
// `throwIfError` is a function that could be used as a callback
// in multiple places.
function throwIfError(err) {
  if(err) {
    // Some code that will tell me that the error originated from a call
    // to `fs.writeFile` in this file (that is, line 13), instead of
    // from the internals of the `writeFile` function. After that, it
    // will throw the same or a new error so that the program will fail
    // early, instead of continuing with the wrong data.
  }
}

require('fs').writeFile(
  'some_non_existent_directory/test.txt',
  '',
  throwIfError
);
```

Comment: Add nodejs and node-fs tags

Comment: You can pass parameter to `throwIfError`

Comment: You can do it in many ways. One common way is `console.error(err);`. This will print the stack trace on the console, and we can trace back to where the error occurred.

Comment: Take for example. `try { console.log(undefined_variabled) } catch (e) { console.log(e)}`. Logging it gives the traceback in both browser and node

Answer (score 0):

Call the callback with an additional argument.

```js
function throwIfError(err, fromwhere) {
  if(err) {
    console.log(`Error came from ${fromwhere}`);
  }
}

require('fs').writeFile(
  'some_non_existent_directory/test.txt',
  '',
  err => throwIfError(err, 'fs.writeFile')
);
```

Comment: Is there a more idiomatic way of doing it? This way, I won't get file and line information. How would you have structured the code for example? Would you not have used a function like `throwIfError` and used arrow functions for every callback?

Comment: Unfortunately, the only built-in mechanism for this (`throwIfError.caller`) is deprecated. The usual way to do this is by using the debugger, not putting it into your exception handler.